# `snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Too many BDL entries` messages in system log

Tags: sound, kernel, intel, 22.10

After today's update of `linux-*-5.19.0-35-generic:amd64` I see many entries in `syslog` like these:

```
Mar  2 12:04:57 xxx kernel: [ 4646.030116] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Too many BDL entries: buffer=2097152, period=65536
Mar  2 12:04:57 xxx kernel: [ 4646.031191] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Too many BDL entries: buffer=1048576, period=32768
Mar  2 12:04:57 xxx kernel: [ 4646.032330] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Too many BDL entries: buffer=2097152, period=65536
Mar  2 12:04:57 xxx kernel: [ 4646.033556] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Too many BDL entries: buffer=1048576, period=32768
Mar  2 12:04:57 xxx kernel: [ 4646.035347] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Too many BDL entries: buffer=4194304, period=131072
```

Previous versions of kernels did not produce such error messages: I searched past system logs of more than one year old.

Some information about my **Ubuntu 22.10 GNOME (Xorg)** notebook computer:

```
$ uname -rv
5.19.0-35-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb 3 18:36:56 UTC 2023
```

It seems that these messages occur during system boot and during log in (around a hundred messages each time).

Any ideas of the meaning of these messages?

Note: Currently, I do *not* have any problems with audio.

---

## Update (2023-04-26)

After update to kernel 6.2 (**Ubuntu 23.04**) these entries ceased to appear.

Comment: I had the same errors also folowing yesterdays updates on Ubuntu 22.10 Wayland. ditto - audio seems to still work. However, this problem has dissapeared when I updated to Ubuntu 23.04

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with my MSI GL73 8SD running Ubuntu 22.10. Like you it started after this kernel update.

Comment: I filled a bug report here : <https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2009271>

Comment: Thanks @LaurentLyaudet !

Comment: Hi! Were you able to find a solution? I have a similar problem and now the audio on my HDMI/Display port is not working. I opened this question about it:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457893/my-hdmi-display-port-audio-stopped-working-on-ubuntu-22-10

Comment: The same problem with kernel `5.19.0-38-generic` too!  :(

Comment: Sorry for you. 5.19.0-38 solved the issue for me. Maybe your hardware is slightly different from mine and you should upload some data about it in the launchpad bug report?

Comment: Same here wanted to reboot. Gnome never launched and when i did login in terminal mode i got a ton of this error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Well I have got issues with my sound card Creative Sound Blaster Z with the new kernel 5.19.0-35.

There was no sound and it said 'dummy audio' in settings. I tried some tricks from the internet but nothing helped, so I had to revert back to kernel 5.19.0.32 and everything works ok

Comment: Thanks for that, I had a similar problem and the audio on my HDMI/DISPLAY port was not working, rolling back the kernel solved my problem.

Answer (score -2):

This solved my issue

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Faced same issue with new kernel 5.19.0-35. It appears there are some issue with NVidia drives. Above step worked for me.

Comment: This did absolutely nothing in my case. I even purged all nvidia packages