# My HDMI/DISPLAY port Audio stopped working on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: drivers, sound, kernel, hdmi, displayport

I've been using Ubuntu 22.10 for quite some time, my HDMI/Display port audio always worked until yesterday when it suddenly stopped working.

I guess some automatic update happened and now the driver can't be recognized by the system anymore, I did some researches and I found this command to give me my installed devices:

`lspci -vk |perl -lne 'print if /Audio/ .. /^[\w]*$/'`

This is the output:

```
    Subsystem: Tul Corporation / PowerColor Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 68
    Memory at fce60000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

09:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 70
    Memory at fc900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

As you can see the first audio device is my monitor connected to an HDMI port it is correctly recognized by the kernel, but it doesn't show to me on the output device option on the system:

[image]

Any suggestion how I can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: See comments on this question: https://askubuntu.com/q/1457367/855322

Comment: Thanks @FedKad, I was able to solve the problem by rolling back the kernel.

Comment: I suspect you're seeing the issue currently being tracked in [LP: #2009136](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2009136), particularly seeing as you've got an AMD Radeon card, and HDMI audio too

Comment: @DaveJones yes it is similar, I reverted the kernel version and now it is working. I have some system updates but I am going to wait longer because I think that problem may happen again after an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by rolling back the kernel.

First list the kernel versions you have:

`apt list --installed | grep linux-image`

This was my output:

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.


linux-image-5.19.0-31-generic/kinetic-updates,kinetic-security,now 5.19.0-31.32 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.19.0-35-generic/kinetic-updates,kinetic-security,now 5.19.0-35.36 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-5.8.0-63-generic/now 5.8.0-63.71~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,local]
linux-image-generic/kinetic-updates,kinetic-security,now 5.19.0.35.32 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

The problematic kernel is usually the latest one, in my case was: `linux-image-5.19.0-35-generic`

Then remove it and restart you computer:

`sudo apt remove linux-image-5.19.0-35-generic`

Here you can find some references about this solution:

[`snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Too many BDL entries` messages in system log](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457367/snd-hda-intel-0000001f-3-too-many-bdl-entries-messages-in-system-log)

https://www.howtogeek.com/740797/how-to-roll-back-the-kernel-in-linux/

Answer (score 1):

Under Ubuntu 22.10, 5.19.17, updating the AMD drivers solved this issue for me (as well as not waking from suspend):

[enter link description here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers)