# Ubuntu 22.04 audio output not working (dummy audio) - No fixes found online solve this

Tags: sound, hdmi

I've tried everything listed everywhere and it's not solving the issue where HDMI audio doesn't work. Video works fine.  I can use my Turtle Beach headphones, but the HDMI audio doesn't work.

There is also no specific cause of this.  It just seemed to stop working.

Doesn't solve:

```
sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager
```

Also:

```
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start
```

Also:

Reinstalling Pulseadio, ALSA, and Pipewire (this uninstalled Gnome, so I reinstalled that as well)

Also:

Installed Pulse Audio Volume Control according to [ItsFoss](https://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-no-sound-through-hdmi-in-external-monitor-in-ubuntu/)

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

The HDMI profile just doesn't populate as shown.

I'm really sick of reinstalling Ubuntu.  It seems like every 4 months something breaks irreparably and the only solution is a clean install.

```
inxi -SMA

System:
  Host: nunya Kernel: 5.19.0-35-generic x86_64 bits: 64

Desktop: GNOME 42.5 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
 Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: CM1735 v: Rev X.0x
 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 0701
 date: 12/13/2012
Audio:
 Device-1: AMD FCH Azalia driver: snd_hda_intel
 Device-2: AMD Oland/Hainan/Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7000 Series]
 driver: snd_hda_intel
 Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-35-generic running: yes
 Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
 Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

Interestingly, inxi shows PulseAudio as running even after I killed it.

/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf has this at the end, no idea if that's appropriate:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic 
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

(also tried "auto" in place of "generic" [according to this](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html), no joy)

Thoughts on anything else I can try?

Comment: The 5.19.0-35 kernel has known problem with hdmi audio.  Drop back to an older kernel in the initial grub menu.

Comment: @ubfan1 make that an answer and I'll select it.  That worked.  Choosing kernel: 5.19.0-32-generic from the advanced boot menu solved it.

Comment: Possibly related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457367/snd-hda-intel-0000001f-3-too-many-bdl-entries-messages-in-system-log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 5.19.0-35 kernel has known problem with hdmi audio. Drop back to an older kernel in the initial grub menu (under advanced...).  Try the next kernel update to see if the problem has been fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately the kernel is gone after a kernel update, now I only have 2 bad versions D: