# persistant loss of sound ("dummy output") after upgrade to 22.04 and 22.10

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, 22.10

I've sunk about 4 hours so far on this and tried all the common solution that have worked for others. I first lost my sound on upgrade to 22.04 and it's still not come back after upgrading to 22.10.

Below what I've tried and output of various diagnostic commands I've seen.

Please help!

## Things tried:

Have tried the following (in some cases multiple times)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade


sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager
sudo alsa force-reload

pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start


sudo ln -s /usr/share/pipewire /etc/pipewire
sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager
systemctl --user start pulseaudio

sudo apt install libldacbt-{abr,enc}2
sudo apt install libspa-0.2-bluetooth pipewire-audio-client-libraries pipewire-media-session
```

### options tried in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

```
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

and also:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

### sudo vim /etc/default/grub

changed:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
To:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="intel_iommu=on,igfx_off"

then, of course:

```
sudo update-grub
reboot
```

## Diagnostic commands:

### erich@erich-nuc:~$ pactl info | grep '^Server Name'

```
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.58)
```

### erich@erich-nuc:~$ cat /proc/asound/modules

```
 0 snd_hda_intel
 1 snd_usb_audio
```

### erich@erich-nuc:~$ aplay -l

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
## erich@erich-nuc:~$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 134
    Memory at b0530000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at b0200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl

--
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 135
    Memory at b0460000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

### erich@erich-nuc:~$ inxi -A

```
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / 560/560X]
    driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-3: Z-Star Micro Venus USB2.0 Camera type: USB
    driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-38-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.58 running: yes

## erich@erich-nuc:~$ sudo lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Coffee Lake HOST and DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Coffee Lake HOST and DRAM Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=10 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore

00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at b0545000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [f0] PCI Advanced Features

00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at b0544000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller (rev 30) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Memory at b0520000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at b053a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=8K]
    Memory at b0543000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3

00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] (rev 30)
    DeviceName:  WIFI
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at b0534000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Null
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [164] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0010 Rev=0 Len=014 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at b053d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at b0541000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    Memory at b0540000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [a4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at b0538000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at b053f000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 4050 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4040 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4020 [size=32]
    Memory at b053e000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=1 Masked-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:19.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Host Controller (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    Memory at b0542000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 121
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 3000-3fff [size=4K] [16-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: b0400000-b04fffff [size=1M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: a0000000-b01fffff [size=258M] [32-bit]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #15 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled] [16-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: b0300000-b03fffff [size=1M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled] [64-bit]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 134
    Memory at b0530000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at b0200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at b053c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at fe010000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (6) I219-V (rev 30)
    DeviceName:  LAN
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (6) I219-V
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    Memory at b0500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Lexa [Radeon 540X/550X/630 / RX 640 / E9171 MCM] (rev c3) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Lexa [Radeon 540X/550X/630 / RX 640 / E9171 MCM]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 136
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at b0400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at b0440000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [200] Physical Resizable BAR
    Capabilities: [270] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [2b0] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [2c0] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Capabilities: [2d0] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [320] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [328] Alternative Routing-ID Interpretation (ARI)
    Capabilities: [370] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu

01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 135
    Memory at b0460000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [328] Alternative Routing-ID Interpretation (ARI)
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Memory at b0300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-01-00-4c-e0-00
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
```

### erich@erich-nuc:~$ uname -r

```
5.19.0-38-generic
```

Comment: Doing an upgrade is never a good way to solve a problem all you did was carry it over.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: I installed Ubuntu 22.10 on a new laptop but I consistently got the `Dummy output`. It turned out that I had configured an audio client (`squeezelite`) to start up at boot. When I removed it, the audio worked as designed.

Comment: @David we may need to agree to disagree!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I just fixed it by upgrading my kernel to 6.0.

Thanks to  [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1458875/86986)

Answer (score 1):

Doing

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install update-manager-core
```

and

```
sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager
sudo alsa force-reload
```

fixed my problem.