# Ubuntu won't boot after kernel or AMD driver updates

Tags: boot, drivers, kernel

I am using Ubuntu 22.10, and I am not using dual boot. I never used Linux or any variants before, so suffice to say I have no idea what I'm doing, after updating my AMD drivers, or so I thought, my laptop won't boot Ubuntu and Ctrl+Alt+F3 displays the login terminal for a while before returning to the image I sent. I thought it was some sort of chkdisk as I am accustomed to windows and I cannot find any info online about what too many BDL entries mean, and that people just know instinctively how to fix it, fix it. I have many files that I have on this computer that I am using for an online course.

[image]

[image: more error]

edit: added a second image to help clarify

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version) and [How to I prevent Ubuntu from kernel version upgrade and notification?](https://askubuntu.com/q/938494/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did wasn't a solution, but I was able to access my files by using the bootable flash drive, installing a new ubuntu partition and then I was able to extract my previous files.
I have yet to attempt a full wipe, but I assume it would fix it.
This has been a real hassle and I'm still not sure what I did wrong, thanks for trying to help me, and Falcone's advice led me to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457367/snd-hda-intel-0000001f-3-too-many-bdl-entries-messages-in-system-log). But I find the [bug related](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2009271)  haven't be fixed. Two solutions are:

1. switch to a previous kernel 5.19.0-31 or earlier
2. Try to install proper drivers following the answer related to **ubuntu-drivers**

Comment: How do I switch to a previous kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Restart the computer after powering off it. When Grub menu comes go to Advance setting in row no 2 one arrow down from top row and select it. From here select recovery mode to fix the problem.

If it does not fix it then use the second recovery mode kernel from advance options. After in Ubuntu environment open the terminal and use following commands.

Sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
.
Hope it solves the problem.

Otherwise download the image and rinstall the 22.10

Comment: So, I am not able to access the Grub with the method you said, the restart button wouldn't work unless I force the restart. With a booteable drive I was able to get to this menu.
https://i.imgur.com/cjIlYIF.jpg


Inside the image I downloaded if I attempt to re-install ubuntu, this shows up

https://i.imgur.com/sfHL432.png

Should I still install it? or make a new ubuntu partition?

I cannot access the terminal to try the commands you sent me, the terminal flashes for a sec then returns to the errors I sent on my first post